# How to print dictionary of dictionaries in dot notation with Jinja2 recursive loop?

Tags: dictionary, recursion, yaml, jinja2

I have the following example of YAML data structure: (data and structure are subject to change)

```
settings:
  subset1:
    sub1: val1
    sub2: val2
    sub3: val3
  subset2: val1
```

I want to use Jinja to print it as such: (ordering is not important)

```
subset1.sub2 = val2
subset1.sub3 = val3
subset1.sub1 = val1
subset2 = val1
```

This is what I have:

```
{% for key, value in settings.items() recursive %}
{{ key }}{% if value is mapping %}.{{ loop(value.items()) }}{% else %} = {{ value }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it gives me this:

```
subset1.sub2 = val2
sub3 = val3
sub1 = val1
subset2 = val1
```

Only the first sub element is printed with its respected parent. How can I print all the sub elements with their respected parents properly?
(Again, ordering is not important)

Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like a ridiculously difficult problem. For a start, add `({{ loop.depth }})` after `{{ key }}` and see what you are really printing (it's not "*the first sub element*", it is the key name of the mapping - you print it only once per iteration of the outer loop). Then think how you can solve this - register key name for each mapping and add another loop inside the inner loop to print all the parent keys.

Comment: Or rather use statements to create a path for each value and then print every single one as a `{{ path }} = {{ value }}` pair.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved my use case:

```
from jinja2 import Template

settings = {
  'k1': {
    'k1': '1.1',
    'k2': {
        'k1': '1.2.1',
        'k2': {
            'k1': '1.2.2.1'
        },
        'k3': {
            'k1': {
                'k1': '1.2.3.1.1'
            },
        },
    },
  },
  'k2': {
    'k1': '2.1'
  },
  'k3': '3'
}

template = """
    {%- macro treedot(dict,string) %}
        {%- for key, value in dict.items() -%}
            {%- if value is mapping -%}
                {%- if string -%}
                    {%- set str = string ~ '.' ~ key  -%}
                {%- else -%}
                    {%- set str = key  -%}
                {%- endif -%}
                {{ treedot(value,str) }}
            {%- else -%}
                {%- if string %}
                    {{ string ~ '.' ~ key }} = {{ value }}
                {%- else %}
                    {{ key }} = {{ value }}
                {%- endif -%}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
    {%- endmacro -%}
    {{ treedot(settings,none) }}
"""
tpl = Template(template)
print tpl.render(settings=settings)
```

The result will be :

```
            k3 = 3
            k2.k1 = 2.1
            k1.k2.k3.k1.k1 = 1.2.3.1.1
            k1.k2.k2.k1 = 1.2.2.1
            k1.k2.k1 = 1.2.1
            k1.k1 = 1.1
```

Better than using the keyword "recursive", using a macro allow recursivity too and allow to pass as an argument the path to the value.
Before this I tried with "recursive" keyword too but wasn't able to achieve my needs since variables inside a loop are reset at each iteration.